# Centos 7 Gnome, blurry image problems

Tags: centos, drivers, display-settings

Sorry for not being very precise, I'm struggling with a problem I fail to identify to be able to find any solution.
[image]

The image you see above is a screenshot of my problem, every time I need to display images or some menus from the Gnome shows that blurry image.

The problem appear after I bought a new second hand laptop Lenovo Thinkpad R500 and I simply removed my disk from the previous (also second hand T61) and everything went "smooth".

I think that the problem might be because of the drivers (but everything looks very normal) or a bad configuration or some settings from the BIOS, but I have no clue where to start. That's why I want to share this in the hope that someone experience the same problem and can share the correct terms to find a solution, and certainly share it here.

In the meantime I continue my hunt.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new text file called /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf with your favorite text editor containing the following text. Since this file resides in the /etc folder and not your home directory, you need root or sudo access to create or edit this file:

Section "Device"

Identifier  "card0"

Driver  "intel"

Option  "AccelMethod"  "uxa"

EndSection